# multiprocessing shared memory in pyqt5 python 3.8

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm a little confused why the following isn't updating the numpy array across processes? There are no errors thrown in this, but the main process doesn't reflect the child's update to the shared array `sample`. I'm unsure why this isn't working. The example on the `shared_memory` page works fine on my machine. The shared events work fine as well. Is this is a Qt-related issue perhaps?

```
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QProgressBar, QPushButton
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import shared_memory
import numpy as np

DATA_SIZE = 1
DTYPE = np.int64


class DataPuller(multiprocessing.get_context("spawn").Process):
    def __init__(
            self,
            event,
            shared_mem_name,
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.event = event
        self.shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shared_mem_name)
        self.sample = np.ndarray(
            shape=(DATA_SIZE, 1), dtype=DTYPE, buffer=self.shm.buf)
        self.counter = 0

    def run(self):
        print("child process started")
        while not self.event.is_set():
            time.sleep(0.1)
            self.sample[:, 0] = self.counter
            print("child: ", self.sample[0, 0])
            self.counter += 1
            if self.counter >= 1000:
                self.counter = 0
        self.shm.close()
        print("child process finished")


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.progressBar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.onTimer)
        self.progressBar.setRange(0, 1000)
        layout.addWidget(self.progressBar)
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton('开启线程', self, clicked=self.onStart))

        self.counter = 0
        self.shared_mem_name = "data"
        self.base_array = np.zeros((DATA_SIZE, 1), dtype=DTYPE)
        self.shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(
            create=True,
            size=self.base_array.nbytes,
            name=self.shared_mem_name)
        self.sample = np.ndarray(
            shape=self.base_array.shape,
            dtype=self.base_array.dtype,
            buffer=self.shm.buf)
        self.event = multiprocessing.Event()
        self._process = DataPuller(self.event, self.shared_mem_name)

    def onStart(self):
        if not self._process.is_alive():
            print("main starting process")
            self._process.start()
            self.timer.start(500)
        else:
            pass

    def onTimer(self):
        print("main: ", self.sample[0, 0])
        self.progressBar.setValue(self.sample[0, 0])

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self._process.is_alive():
            self.event.set()
            self._process.join()
        self.shm.close()
        self.shm.unlink()
        self.close()
        print("main process finished")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Event does not belong to the DataPuller context so it will never enter the while. The solution is to create the Event using the context.

The problem is that the __init__ method of DataPuller is executed in the initial process where shared memory is created so it is not available for the secondary DataPuller process. The solution in this case is to create the shared memory in the run method.

```py
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QProgressBar, QPushButton
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import shared_memory
import numpy as np

DATA_SIZE = 1
DTYPE = np.int64

context = multiprocessing.get_context("spawn")


class DataPuller(context.Process):
    def __init__(
        self, event, shared_mem_name,
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.event = event
        self.shared_mem_name = shared_mem_name

    def run(self):
        self.shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=self.shared_mem_name)
        self.sample = np.ndarray(shape=(DATA_SIZE, 1), dtype=DTYPE, buffer=self.shm.buf)
        self.counter = 0

        while not self.event.is_set():
            time.sleep(0.1)
            self.sample[:, 0] = self.counter
            print("child: ", self.sample[0, 0])
            self.counter += 1
            if self.counter >= 1000:
                self.counter = 0
        self.shm.close()
        print("child process finished")


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.progressBar = QProgressBar()
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.onTimer)
        self.progressBar.setRange(0, 1000)
        layout.addWidget(self.progressBar)
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton("开启线程", clicked=self.onStart))

        self.counter = 0
        self.shared_mem_name = "data"
        self.base_array = np.zeros((DATA_SIZE, 1), dtype=DTYPE)
        self.shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(
            create=True, size=self.base_array.nbytes, name=self.shared_mem_name
        )
        self.sample = np.ndarray(
            shape=self.base_array.shape,
            dtype=self.base_array.dtype,
            buffer=self.shm.buf,
        )
        self.event = context.Event()
        print(self.event.is_set())
        self._process = DataPuller(self.event, self.shared_mem_name)

    def onStart(self):
        if not self._process.is_alive():
            print("main starting process")
            self._process.start()
            self.timer.start(500)
        else:
            pass

    def onTimer(self):
        print("main: ", self.sample[0, 0])
        self.progressBar.setValue(self.sample[0, 0])

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self._process.is_alive():
            self.event.set()
            self._process.join()
        self.shm.close()
        self.shm.unlink()
        self.close()
        print("main process finished")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This makes sense, and is something I overlooked. Thanks. However-- the issue remains that shared_memory is not working as I expect. That is, if you run the code you will see that the while is indeed entered.

Comment: @stevesteverson Is it necessary to use contexts?

Comment: In the larger context, for my application to be portable I would like to limit process generation to "spawn" rather than "fork"... do you think this is an issue with contexts? Let me test without and report back.

Comment: Ah. I see what you're getting at. Changing `context = multiprocessing.get_context("spawn")` to `context = multiprocessing.get_context("fork")` and it works. The trouble is I need this to work on Windows and OSX.

Comment: @stevesteverson It is that the contexts limit the scope of the variables that can be shared and it seems that this is the case, if a context is not used the code works

Comment: @stevesteverson what is your OS? I  use linux

Comment: Surely there must be a workaround? It is not mentioned in the docs...

Comment: And actually from the docs: `Changed in version 3.8: On macOS, the spawn start method is now the default. The fork start method should be considered unsafe as it can lead to crashes of the subprocess.` EDIT: I see the problem, I was conflating `context` with `start method`. I assume on Windows I can simply use `multiprocessing.use_start_method("spawn") whereas in OSX it's default.

Comment: Yes-- I was incorrectly using the context to simply set the start method, as I didn't quite get the difference between the two. I just need to make sure the start method is `spawn` when running on Windows, but there should be no need to set a context. Do you agree?

Comment: Got it. THAT makes more sense. Subtle. So for future reference-- contexts are for using multiple start methods throughout an application, and the `__init__` runs in the parent process. Great work team. Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear: `fork` works in this case because the handles created in the parent are copied to the child, but this is not the case for `spawn`.